# Symfony ACL - How to update acl object?

Tags: symfony, acl

I want to update previously wrote (or insert a new if not exist) ACL. What Im trying to do is not work:

```
public function upgradeUser(User $user, Model $model)
    {
        $acl = null;
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($model);
        $securityIdentity= UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        try {
            $acl = $this->aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);

            /** @var Entry[] $aces */
            $aces = $acl->getObjectAces();
            foreach($aces as $i => $ace) {
                if ($securityIdentity->equals($securityIdentity)) {
                    $acl->updateObjectAce($i, $ace->getMask() & MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR);
                }
            }

        } catch (AclNotFoundException $e) {
            $acl = $this->aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
            $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR);
        }

        $this->aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the insert section work or both? To me it seems insertion should not happen because you never throw any exception if user not found. Does it show up any message? Are you sure by `&` with MASK_OPERATOR you will produce the proper mask?

Comment: Whether you check the entity is identical to itself? `$securityIdentity->equals($securityIdentity)`

Comment: @galago, sorry it was typo. I've found solution, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the wrong "insert" process. The solution is to use InserObjectAcl method when updated objected was not found:

```
protected function addMask(SecurityIdentityInterface $securityIdentity, $mask, $acl, $appendMask = true)
    {
        // flag to determine if mask was really updated or not
        $isUpdated = false;

        // go throw all aces and try to find current user's ace
        foreach ($acl->getObjectAces() as $ace) {
            if (!($ace instanceof Entry) || !$ace->getSecurityIdentity()->equals($securityIdentity))
                continue;

            $maskBuilder = new MaskBuilder($appendMask ? $ace->getMask() : 0);
            $maskBuilder->add($mask);
            $ace->setMask($maskBuilder->get());

            $isUpdated = true;
            break;
        }

        // in the case if object was not found in aces for this user, insert a new ace
        if ($isUpdated === false)
            $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, $mask);
    }
```